# Error : image could not be created from at app.createWindow in electronjs

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application

I am learning the electronjs. I am getting this error on one of example electron project i just started.

> Error : image could not be created from at app.createWindow in C:\Users\GS\Desktop\electron\example4\index.js 21:3
>   here is the index.js file code

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
function createWindow () {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
}
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

I don't know why this is happening but i copied the same code which is working in another example project i create one day ago. May be it is very basic question, but i am trying to figure out from last 4-5 hours and still i don't find any solution. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer (@free-dom) is correct, although it is not necessary to declare the `mainwindow` variable outside of the function. as if you don't declare the `mainwindow` outside of the function then you have to call like this `app.whenReady().then(createWindow)`

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
function createWindow () {
    let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
}
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `mainWindow` must be declared outside the function `createWindow ()`, otherwise the `BrowserWindow` object it represents won't remain valid (will get garbage-collected) right after the function is exited from. This should fix the issue:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let mainWindow = null;
function createWindow () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
}
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```